# ErrorException: Undefined index: ELEMENT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm testing this code using Laravel's dusk, but seems to get an **ErrorException: Undefined index: ELEMENT** error upon running dusk. Please advise.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\SiteConfig;

/**
 * @group login
 */
class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{

 /**
     * @group logo
     */
    public function testIsCompanyLogoShownOnLogin()
    {
        $config = SiteConfig::where('name', 'company_logo')->first();

        if (!$config) {
             $config = factory(SiteConfig::class)->create(['name' => 'company_logo', 'value' => '']);
        }

        $path = url('/storage/company_logo/15710448965da43e201017e.png');
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($path) {
             $browser->maximize();
             $browser->visit('/')
                ->pause(3000)
                ->assertVisible('img[src="' . $path . '"]');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `stack trace`. Which file causes the error?

Comment: This is now working. I just run the command php artisan dusk --group logo again.